# How to view pdf while working with mpdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I am working on codeignitor and doing work for generating report. But my problem is that everytime i ve to download pdf file to view anything which is taking seriously too much time.

Here is the link of mpdf manual http://www.mpdfonline.com/repos/mpdfmanual.pdf

here is my code which i am working. If somebody know something plz help:

**Controller:**
Report.php

```
public function index(){
    $html =$this->load->view('report/index', $this->data, true);
    $htmls=$html;
    $this->load->library('Mpdf_land');    
    $pdfFilePath = 'Public_Opportunities_Detail('.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').').pdf';                  
    $this->mpdf_land->pdf->WriteHTML($htmls);
    $this->mpdf_land->pdf->Output(UPLOAD_REPORT_PATH.$pdfFilePath.'', "D");
}
```

**View File**: index.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>hello </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the "D" in output function to "I" `$this->mpdf_land->pdf->Output(UPLOAD_REPORT_PATH.$pdfFilePath.'', "I");`
so then file should be displayed inline in browser instead of downloading it.

Or if it is only the matter of HTML output in developing and you don't need the pdf at all you can just print it. Something like `print_r($htmls); exit;`

Comment: Thanks buddy... really help ful

Comment: one thing more is there anyway that i shd inspect pdf as well and bring changes while developing??